# HWUT - selectively printing from read buffer into .exe file in OUT folder

Tags: serial-communication, hwut

I am receiving data from serial port. I use HWUT for comparing my test results. The content from receive buffer cannot be directly used for comparison of GOOD and OUT result. Becuase the OUT will always have unnecessary command prompts, enters and other stuff. I am looking to select what must be written from read buffer into OUT file. For example below is an example

```
←[36m
A> target cmd
                ←[36m
{t=3883.744541 s} Received data 
A>             result :  1
                       bytes read 518Closing serial port...OK
```

And I would like the out file to only have 'result : 1'.
When i checked the code, messages.py seems to be printing to std out. But not sure if that is being used for printing into OUT file. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that you print to 'stdout' should appear in the "OUT/*" files. If it does not, then this would have nothing to do with receiption via serial line(s). Here is what I would do to analyze:

1. In your connector application there must be something like

   `receive_n = receive(.., &buffer[0], Size);
   buffer[receive_n] = '\0'; /* terminating zero */
   printf("%s", &buffer[0]);`

   If this is so, then
2. Write in paralell into a log file.

   `static log_fh = fopen("tmp.log", "wb");
   ...
   printf("%s", &buffer[0]);
   fwrite((void*)buffer, 1, received_n, log_fh);`
3. Compare 'tmp.log' with the file in OUT.

   If there is a difference, HWUT is to blame.
4. Check the output before you write it.

   if( my_condition(buffer, received_n) ) printf("%s", &buffer[0]);

HWUT has an internal infrastructure to post-process test output, but it is not documented and therefore not reliable--at the time of this writing.

Comment: Hi Frank,  I think my question was not clear. There is no problem here with HWUT. What is printed into OUT file exactly what came into recevie buffer. But whatever comes from the receive buffer cannot be used as it is for comparison. So I am looking to filter out contents. I would like to print into a file using filtering option only stuff that i want. For example in the above case, lets say i only want result : 1 for comparison.

Comment: Hi Frank, I created execute-this.sh in the same folder where my application stays, and i dont see this file being used by --hwut-info. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file "hwut-info.dat" in your TEST directory.

```
These R my Tests on Something Important (Title)
-------------------------------------------------------
--not  *.exe
bash   execute-this.sh
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The `--not *.exe` makes sure that HWUT will **not** execute the *.exe files which you compiled. The `bash execute-this.sh` line lets HWUT consider the file `execute-this.sh` as a test application and call it with 'bash'.

Inside the `execute-this.sh` you might want to make your application, execute it and filter the output, i.e.

```
#! bash
make my-test.exe
./my-test.exe | awk ' /^A>/ '
```

which will print only those lines which start with 'A>'. `grep` and `awk` are your friends, here. You might want to familiarize yourself with these two.

Alternatively, you may filter directly in your connection application.

Comment: The shell script needs to respond to "--hwut-info" as shown in http://hwut.sourceforge.net/html/deterministic/choices.html